# Discover context in word alignement

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

I am using [Facebook Muse](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE) to [translate](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE/blob/main/demo.ipynb) words from one language to another, and apparently it performs well (I set no metric though). Although I have very basic ML/Datascience/NLP knowledge, could you please guide me to translating not only one word but two and maybe three words. I am not looking for very accurate translations like with tense and prepositions and so on. I am looking for approximate translation even say up to 70% is very fine for my case.

In other words, is it possible somehow to translate for instance: `bat` correctly in `baseball bat` knowing it is so different from `bat` in `bat wings`, in this situation, probably the context could help but I'm not sure how or even if this is possible using these alignment models ?

Comment: You can use gemsim vectors  to find word similarity . You know  phrase in which word appears

Comment: @amolgoel "You know phrase in which word appears" I didn't understand that. please elaborate.

Comment: The bird was flying in the garden. Word is bird. Phrase is the sentence. Find all possible synonyms of bird: animal, badminton. Find similarity between synonym and phrase. Choose the one with highest similarity

Comment: Actually I thought of something like that frankly, but putting it with words, fixed that in my brain. So yes, thanks a lot!